# Do imaginary measurements exists?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, eigenvalue, complex-numbers, observables

I'm sorry if this question is too metaphysical, but I will give it a try.

My textbook in introductory quantum mechanics is basing a lot of its proof and derivations on the fact that the value of the measurement must be a real value, hence no imaginary part. This is stated as something obvious and in a way taken as an axiom.

Is there any example of a measurement that is in fact a complex or imaginary number, and even if there is not, is it a bit naive to state that there can't be complex measurements? We may indeed measure non-rational values, negative values even though these numbers were not always considered numbers.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82613/2451

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Only Real Things Measurable?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82613/)

Comment: Do you have an example of a measurement giving a non-rational value?