# Self-adjoint operators quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, observables

What is the role of self-adjoint operators in the formalism of
quantum mechanics? Is there any clear cut answer to this... like a one sentence answer? Thanks.

Comment: Well, to make some (useful) theorems work, for example.

Comment: Can close voters please comment to explain to OP (who is new to asking questions) if there is anything wrong with his question, so that he or she can learn how to improve if that is the case rather than having the question silently closed. In addition I personally do not see this as a do-my-homework question, which I can see as the close reason due to higher reputation. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39602/2451 and links therein.