# Non-Hermitian operator with real eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, measurements, hilbert-space, observables

So we know that in Quantum Mechanics we require the operators to be Hermitian, so that their eigenvalues are real ($\in \mathbb{R}$) because they correspond to observables.

What about a non-Hermitian operator which, among the others, also has real ($\mathbb{R}$) eigenvalues? Would they correspond to observables? If no, why not?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16678/2451) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39602/2451) Phys.SE questions.

Comment: They don't say anything about whether or not a measurement of that quantity can be performed

Comment: Yes they do. The answer given there says that there will in general be non-zero overlap between the eigenstates that are not orthogonal. Thus measuring an eigenvalue would not be a guarantee that the system is in the corresponding eigenstate. In the Copenhagen interpretation, the collapse of the wave function is no longer a well-defined procedure. So a non-Hermitian operator is not a well-defined observable.

Comment: Right I meant there is no yes/no answer in there, which is what I was looking for.
You say that "measuring an eigenvalue would not be a guarantee that the system is in the corresponding eigenstate", but can that eigenvalue (real, but of a non-Hermitian matrix) be measured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Hermitian matrices eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal. This guarantees that not only are the eigenvalues real, expectation values are too.

Comment: so for a non-Hermitian operator the eigenvectors corresponding to the real eigenvalues are not orthogonal?
I realise this means that one cannot know which eigenstate the wavefunction collapsed to, but do these eigenvalues correspond to observables? Can you measure them?