# How does the Hermiticity of an operator imply that functions have an expansion in in multiple bases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space

In Shankar QM it is stated that since the $\boldsymbol K$ operator is Hermitian, vectors, which are expanded in the $\boldsymbol X$ basis with components $f(x) = \langle x | f \rangle$, must have an expansion in the $\boldsymbol K$ basis (i.e. the eigenbasis of $\boldsymbol K$).

Why is this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with being Hermitian. You can express vectors and operators in whatever basis you want. The definition of a basis is that you can do this. I think you aren't quite asking what you mean to ask.

Comment: That's what I thought, but he seemed to go out of the way to make the distinction. It was in a comment which set up the Fourier Transform as the Transformation from $\boldsymbol X$ to $\boldsymbol K$

Comment: @DanielSank well the basis does have to be complete to do that. I'm guessing the $\boldsymbol K$ basis is supposed to be the eigenbasis of the operator, so the question boils down to whether the eigenbasis of a Hermitian operator is complete. kypalmer can you confirm? (and edit your question accordingly)

Comment: @DavidZ: What's a "basis" if it's not complete? To me "basis" means "complete set of vectors".

Comment: @DanielSank The $K$ basis is indeed meant to mean the eigenbasis of $K$. I've edited to make sure this is clear.

Comment: Again, you're asking why a vector can be expanded in two different bases. The answer is because a basis is *defined* as a set of vectors in which you can expand any other vector.

Comment: @DanielSank from [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109473/is-there-any-non-hermitian-operator-on-hilbert-space-with-all-real-eigenvalues/152896#152896) linked answer it seems to me that an operator which is Hermetian will always have a complete eigenbasis in the Physical-Hilbert space. Does this seem right to you?

Comment: @DanielSank Can you help me understand, then, the circumstances where a basis would be incomplete, such that we could not expand functions expanded in $\boldsymbol X$ into $\boldsymbol K$?

Comment: Ah! That's a different question. Yes, given any Hermitian operator $K$ there is guaranteed to exist a basis such that every element in that basis is an eigenvector of $K$. From the way you worded your original question, where you simply refer to "the $K$ basis" it is already implied that this exists, so I didn't think you were asking about that.

Comment: @DanielSank (6 comments up) I thought there was such a thing as an incomplete basis, which is a set of linearly independent vectors that don't span the space. A basis of a subspace. But it's been a long time since linear algebra class so I might be wrong.

Comment: @DavidZ: I wouldn't call "a basis of a subspace" a "basis" without further qualification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theorem.** If $\hat{K}$ is Hermitian then the eigenvectors of $\hat{K}$ can be chosen so as to form an orthonormal basis $|\xi_i\rangle$.

(The "can be chosen" wording completely handles the cases of degenerate eigenvalues, and the fact that an eigenvector times a constant is still an eigenvector)

(the converse is not true. In fact replace the word "Hermitian" with "Normal" and the theorem still holds. See: [the wikipedia page on the spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem). Also, I'm mainly considering the finite dimensional case)

**Theorem.** If $\{|\xi_i\rangle\}$ forms an orthonormal basis, then $I=\sum |\xi_i\rangle \langle \xi_i|$, where $I$ is the identity operator.

So, if your vector is $|\varphi\rangle$, you can also write it as $|\varphi\rangle=I|\varphi\rangle=\sum |\xi_i\rangle \langle \xi_i|\varphi\rangle$

if you're in a basis given by $\{ |n\rangle \}$, then $\langle n|\varphi\rangle$ are your components and $I=\sum |\xi_i\rangle \langle \xi_i|=\sum |n\rangle \langle n|$, so:

$|\varphi\rangle=II|\varphi\rangle=\sum_{i,n}|\xi_i\rangle \langle \xi_i|n\rangle \langle n|\varphi\rangle$

which is a change of basis represented by matrix multiplication, with $\langle \xi_i|n\rangle$ being the matrix elements.

My point in all this is that those two theorems when combined with Dirac notation are very nice!

**Bonus**:

Consider two particularly interesting bases:

1. The basis of delta functions $\{|x\rangle\}$ where $\langle x | y\rangle =\delta(x - y)$. The $|x\rangle$ vectors are vectors with specific position in space.
2. The basis of exponentials $\{|\nu \rangle\}$ where $\langle x | \nu \rangle = e^{i 2 \pi \nu x}$. These have specific spatial frequency. Note that $\langle \nu | \mu \rangle = \delta(\nu - \mu)$.

Now consider the equation we had at the end of the previous section:

\begin{align}
|f\rangle
&= \int dx d\nu | \nu \rangle \langle \nu | x \rangle \langle x | f \rangle \\
\langle \nu' | f \rangle &= \int dx d\nu \langle \nu'| \nu \rangle e^{-i 2 \pi \nu x} f(x)\\
&= \int dx d\nu \delta(\nu - \nu') e^{-i 2 \pi \nu px} f(x) \\
\tilde{f}(\nu') &= \int dx \, e^{-i 2 \pi \nu' x} f(x) \, .
\end{align}
So yeah, the Fourier transform is a change of basis.

Comment: By the way, using this nice notation you can explain Green's functions and essentially every use of linear algebra in physics.

Comment: So, basically, as long as both $ | \xi_i \rangle$ and $ |n\rangle$ are complete bases, then they are equivalent in their ability to describe any vector. Is this right? Does any of this change for an infinite dimensional function space?

Comment: @kypalmer: Glad you asked. Check out my edit to the answer. The "reason" the exponentials $\exp{i 2\pi \nu x}$ form a complete basis is that they are the eigenvectors (eigenfunctions) of the Hermitian operator $-iD$ where $D$ is the derivative with respect to $x$! I have written a very extensive and pedagogical document on this topic. If you would like me to email you a copy you can find my email address on my profile page. Don't be shy! I wrote it to help people like you.

Comment: There it is! Good extension to infinite dim.