# Imaginary part of complex non-Hermitian Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, complex-numbers, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

I have just started studying the $PT$-symmetric and non-hermitian hamiltonians.
But I am not able to interpret the imaginary part of the hamiltonian. If Hamiltonian is basically the total energy of the system then how can it be complex?

please help.

Comment: The Hamiltonian is not required to be the energy, not even classically, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194772/50583.

Comment: Appart from what @ACuriousMind said, in QM the Hamiltonian is just an operator, energies come from its eigenvalues. If $H$ is hermitian, all its eigenvalues are real, but there are some non-hermitian hamiltonian with real eigenvalues. More info here (https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105563/) and links therein.

Comment: Thank you for your help!